# Delphi project - debug x release version - problem with Indy library

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, indy, indy10

We have port an application from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2007 - and the communication between server and client from Indy 9 to Indy 10.

The part that checks the username and password is now giving some really weird results:
If I'm on my Virtual Machine (development environment) with Delphi 2007, I can login into the server application no problem.

If I generate the executables and try to run it outside the virtual machine, I get a wrong password.
The code that checks for the password reads the data using a TIdTCPConnection.ReadString - for Delphi 7 and a 
TidTCPConnection.Socket.ReadString on Delphi 2007.

I was guessing this was related, somehow, with the extra parameters on Delphi 2007 version for the ReadString method but then, why I can login when I run the application in Debug mode - either running the server in Debug or the client in Debug but not able to connect outside my Delphi 2007 environment.

Is there any DLL or other file that I am missing here?

Any help, even pointing the right direction, is much appreciated - we are stucked on it since yesterday.

**EDITED - EDITED - EDITED - EDITED - EDITED - EDITED:**

I have changed the title for this question, and have isolated the problem that is only happening with the release version of the application.
With a debug version, including TD32, debug info, local symbols, debug DCU, etc, the problem just not happen.

The machine where I'm testing the release and debug version only have Delphi 7 installed.
The one generating the executables, with Finalbuilder, have Delphi 7 and Delphi 2007 (the compiler version being used).

I have another virtual machine, that I use to develop Delphi 2007 projects - anything generated on this machine - debug version, works fine as well - but release version - without debug information, will have the same password problem.

Comment: I suggest you elaborate on _I get a wrong password_ .  Is it different from what you send? how is it different?

Comment: The routine tries to compare the password sent from the client to the server - it does some fancy stuff as generating a random string, mixing and then comparing - but I isolated the problem on the password reading - its a different value... I'm following Alan recommendation to see how it goes...

Comment: How do I change the question to what you are suggesting?

Comment: In release you can log the password you're sending and the password you're receiving to a plain text files. I suggest you show us what you sent and what you got.

Comment: I have isolate the problem further more.
For memory management we use FastMM - not the bundled version, but the latest one. Whenever the FullDebug directive is set to false, the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using OutputDebugString or logging the password to a file on the server side, to ensure it is receiving it correctly.

Also, are you using the latest version of Indy?  There may be fixes pertaining to string handling.

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard to diagnose without seeing your actual code and data.  Most likely, when you made the switch from Indy 9 to 10, your Indy 10 code is not actually using the correct functionality that is equivilent to your Indy 9 code.  Please provide more details.